# Minimum Principle Substituting, Why?

Tags: complex-analysis

In The Pommerenke book "Univalent Functions" and in the process of proving Corollary 1.4. we must calculate dist(0,∂F) by minimum principle, I don't know why we can substitute $\liminf_{|z|\to1}|\frac{f(z)}{z}|$ with $\liminf_{|z|\to1}|f(z)|$ and it will be less than or equal 1.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Pommerenke's book to hand. However, this appears trivial: 
$$ \liminf_{|z|\to 1} \left|\frac{f(z)}{z}\right| =
   \frac{\liminf_{|z|\to 1} |f(z)|}{\lim_{|z|\to 1}|z|} = \liminf_{|z|\to 1} |f(z)|. $$

(This is justified, of course, by the fact that the limit in the denominator exists and is non-zero.)